# Delete subset of a table based on temp table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have a table, say `myTable`. I also have a temp table, say `myTableTemp`, that contains the exact values I want to <s>keep</s> *eliminate* from `myTable` (`myTable` has more value than I need).

I was initially thinking I could drop myTable, and then rename `myTableTemp` to myTable`. However there are many FK contraints that I do not want to touch. In theory, my query would look like:

```
DELETE FROM myTable where in (myTableTemp);
```

At least logically that is how  i think about it

EDIT: The temp table contains the data I want to DELETE from `myTable`

Comment: you'll need to match on something (probably a PK), so more like `DELETE FROM myTable where id in (Select id from myTableTemp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate solution to *eliminate* from `myTable` items present in `myTableTemp`:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
 WHERE primary_key IN ( SELECT primary_key FROM myTableTemp )
;
```

It is usually believed that `[NOT] EXISTS` queries perform better than those using `[NOT] IN`. But [it is not always that obvious](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684).

Comment: I think the optimizer will usually handle the two exactly the same unless it's a complex query. I've not noticed a lot of performance difference myself. In Oracle 9i and below, I think, the `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS` version would be necessary in the case of composite primary keys (before support for tuples with `IN` was added).

Comment: @David Yes, you're perfectly right. The one key difference between `[NOT] EXISTS` and `[NOT] IN` is when you need to delete value based on a possibly `NULL` key, as `NULL` is neither `IN` nor `NOT IN` anything. But this is not the case here as we use primary key to identify rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM myTable where in (myTableTemp);
```

Isn't the above backwards? Don't you want to keep all the values in `myTableTemp`?

I would do the following:

```
DELETE FROM myTable t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM myTableTemp t2
                     WHERE t2.primary_key = t1.primary_key );
```

Again, that's assuming that you want to keep everything in `myTableTemp` and delete everything in `myTable` that isn't in `myTableTemp`.

Comment: I made an edit. The `myTableTemp` has the data I want to *eliminate* from `myTable`.

Comment: Also, what is the `SELECT 1` for? I've heard it improves performance. Is that why you used it?

Comment: If you want to eliminate those records, use WHERE EXISTS instead of WHERE NOT EXISTS. The 1 in SELECT 1 can be anything - 1 is convenient.